# Fancy blue message boxes in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

is there a way to create those nice fancy blue messageboxes with greyed out background, like Windows Update uses, from PowerShell? [like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eqiG.jpg)

Thanks in advance!
V.Steiger

Comment: I don't think so, but you can create [toast notifications](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast)

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate this by creating a couple of related windows forms and styling them correctly.  Here is an example that is only very roughly styled.

Note: ALT+F4 will exit the form.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")  
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
[void] [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() 

$backgroundForm = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form 
$backgroundForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" 


$backgroundForm.WindowState = [System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState]::Maximized
$backgroundForm.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::SizableToolWindow
$backgroundForm.ControlBox = $false
$backgroundForm.ShowInTaskbar = $False
$backgroundForm.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Black
$backgroundForm.Opacity = .5
$backgroundForm.Text = ''
$backgroundForm.TopMost = $true



$backgroundForm.add_Shown({
    param([object]$sender, [System.EventArgs]$e)
    
    $msgForm = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form 
    $msgForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" 


    $msgForm.Width = 400
    $msgForm.Height = 250
    $msgForm.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::None
    $msgForm.ControlBox = $false
    $msgForm.ShowInTaskbar = $False
    $msgForm.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Blue
    $msgForm.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White
    $msgForm.Text = ''
    $msgForm.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial",15,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold) 
    
    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label 
    $label.Text = "You'll need to style as appropriate" 
    $label.AutoSize = $true 
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50) 

    $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label 
    $button.Text = 'Close'
    $button.AutoSize = $true
    $button.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::FixedSingle
    $button.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter
    $button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
    

    $button.add_Click({
        param([object]$sender, [System.EventArgs]$e)

        $sender.Parent.Close()
    })


    $msgForm.Controls.Add($Label) 
    $msgForm.Controls.Add($button) 

    $msgForm.Modal = $true
    
    $msgForm.ShowDialog($sender)

    $sender.Close()
    
})

$backgroundForm.ShowDialog()
```